# Crosscompiling C for windows on linux, getting a compiler error

Tags: c, linux, mingw, cross-compiling

All,

I'm using the mingw32 tool chain to do some cross compiling on a linux platform. Everything has been working out fine, until I included `<error.h>` from the standard library. Now mingw32 spits out a compiler error, saying it can't find `error.h`.

While this is a GNU extension, I'm also using GNU `getopts.h`, which does work. So, why do I get this problem? Following is a verbose output:

```
[09:57:48]$ i586-mingw32msvc-gcc scanner.c -O -Wall  -o brookfieldSplitter.exe -v 2>&1 | sed ':1;s,/[^/.][^/]*/\\.\\./,/,;t 1'
Using built-in specs.
Target: i586-mingw32msvc
Configured with: /build/buildd/mingw32-4.2.1.dfsg/build_dir/src/gcc-4.2.1-2-dfsg/configure -v --prefix=/usr --target=i586-mingw32msvc --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads --enable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-multilib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.2.1-sjlj (mingw32-2)
 /usr/libexec/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/cc1 -quiet -v scanner.c -quiet -dumpbase scanner.c -mtune=pentium -auxbase scanner -O -Wall -version -o /tmp/cc4itePc.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/sys-include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/include
 /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include
End of search list.
GNU C version 4.2.1-sjlj (mingw32-2) (i586-mingw32msvc)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.4.4.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 593b76e6db3b48c579d5ccd7737af5b4
scanner.l:53:19: error: error.h: No such file or directory
scanner.l: In function 'main':
scanner.l:638: warning: implicit declaration of function 'error'
```

As noted on this [mingw32 wiki page](http://mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO), there are differences between the search paths for gcc and mingw32. You can see in the above output where it searches for `#include` items.

Contents of `locate error.h` as requested:

```
[10:44:42]$ locate error.h
/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/raserror.h
/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/winerror.h
/usr/include/error.h
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gdbuserror.h
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioerror.h
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gerror.h
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/error.h
/usr/include/linux/can/error.h
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/gplinclude/disk/error.h
/usr/share/doc/ipython/manual/html/api/generated/IPython.kernel.core.error.html
/usr/share/doc/ipython/manual/html/api/generated/IPython.kernel.error.html
/usr/share/pgadmin3/docs/cs_CZ/connect-error.html
/usr/share/pgadmin3/docs/en_US/connect-error.html
/usr/share/pgadmin3/docs/fr_FR/connect-error.html
/usr/share/webkitgtk-1.0/webkit-1.0/resources/error.html
/usr/share/webkitgtk-3.0/webkit-3.0/resources/error.html
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12/arch/ia64/sn/include/ioerror.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12/arch/mips/include/asm/fw/cfe/cfe_error.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12/include/linux/can/error.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic/include/config/ata/verbose/error.h
```

<strike>Why does mingw32 include the GNU extension `getopt` but not `error`?</strike> As noted by Ignacio below, getopt is POSIX. And what is the easiest way to work around this problem?

- Drop to ISO C?
- Add /usr/include to search path for compiler?
- Copy `error` into /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/ ?

Comment: This doesn't look like a **linker** error at all. Try `locate error.h` does the file exist in the place you pointed your GCC to?

Comment: "Can't find error.h" is a compiler error, not a linker error.  Oh, and there's no `error.h` in the standard C library.  Did you mean `errno.h`?

Comment: Is there an `error.h` in your cross compiler's include dir?

Comment: Ahhh...i see one in /usr/include on my Linux box.  Not sure whether Windows would include it too.

Comment: @larsmans Nope, that's the problem. As I stated, it is a GNU extension just like `getopt`. What surprised me is how `getopt` is included, but `error` is not. This brings up the question is it unsupported, or do I just need to use the copy I have in `/usr/include`?

Comment: There exists a getopt implementation as part of the MinGW runtime. Use that one ;)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED I am using that one, which is why `mingw32` can find it...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ah, that explains that.

Comment: I'll try again: the **MinGW runtime** from my remark was not about the compiler you use but about a library you'll want to use. And believe me it does work, I am using it. It works even **on** Windows, not just when cross-compiling from Linux for Windows. From the command lines I cannot see any indication you use it. It comes with its own headers as well.

Comment: What do you need error.h for? Maybe switching to [Boost.system](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/system/doc/index.html) is an alternative for you?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Yes, I understand that. My question is not about `getopt`, which does work. It is about `error` which does not work. I've added the results of `locate error.h` as you requested.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: boost with C? ... interesting thought.

Comment: @ComicSansMS this is straight C, not C++. I'm using error because it defines the function error, [as documented here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html#Error-Messages). I can use the ISO standard perror successfully, but error wraps a couple things together for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header `error.h`, as you linked in your last comment at the time of this writing, is part of GNU libc, aka glibc, aka the GNU system's C library.

You are compiling for *Windows*, it does not have GNU libc, it uses msvcr*. You cannot magically cross-compile Linux/GNU code like this and expect it to work.

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to as well. When I first started this, I thought that since `getopt` worked, then `error` would work as well. As Ignacio noted in his comment, `getopt` is POSIX. That's why *it* works. I've migrated back to ISO standard error message handling at this point.

Comment: `getopt` being POSIX is not a reason it works on MinGW. Most of POSIX is impossible to implement in a msvcrt-compatible way (like `locale_t` extensions), so doing that would mean having to rewrite all of the C runtime and incompatibility with the Windows system C runtime. MinGW implemented this little part of POSIX (and a few others), but do not rely on POSIX or GNU documentation when writing Windows code. Use msdn.com. It's quite extensive.

Comment: I wish that was more clearly stated in the documentation for cross compiling then. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun This has nothing to do with cross-compiling an sich. This is equally applicable to compiling on another platform natively. You're building code for that platform, so you have to use that platform's library. If you were to cross-compile to Linux, the documentation would be wildly different (you'd check developer.apple.com obviously).